# multiple table update sailsjs mysql

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am working on this little app nba_manager_simulator, and I'm stuck creating contracts between a team and a player.
The contract is a table, team another, and player a third (the contract has 1 team, 1 player, 2 dates (begining, end) and 1 decimal (salary).

The problem is : when I create a new contract, it doesnt add the contract id to the player.

I'm trying to add it by making a query like so :

```
Player.query(update player set fk_contract = $1 where player.id = $2, [contract.id][contract.fk_player]...)
```

but it tells me that $2 is unknown.

What's the correct 'Sails' way to do it ?
And what's the "query" way ? (I'd like to know more about SQL queries in Sails)

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL queries use `?` as placeholder whereas PostgreSQL queries use `$1, $2`. [Examples](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query#?example)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that but i didnt know how to put it with multiple params, and I thought that using $1, $2... would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need pass both parameters in the same array, not separate ones, like this:

```
let sql = 'update player set fk_contract = $1 where player.id = $2'
Player.query(sql, [contract.id, contract.fk_player]...)
```

Comment: Okay i had 3 mistakes here, :first using $1 instead of ? as pointed by Sangharsh, second i used "contract.fk_player.id" instead of simply fk_player, and third, using multiple arrays... now it works just fine. Thanks guys!